# How to make a symbol non walkable in a C# cmd game?

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to make a sort of CMD "dungeon crawler thing" game.

In it the walls or "**#**" these should be non walkable.

This is an excerpt or what i have so far

```
    static bool Walkable;
    static string Wall = "#";
    static string Player = "@";
    static int PX = 52, PY = 12;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Draw();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(PX, PY);
            Console.Write(Player, Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            ConsoleKeyInfo mov = Console.ReadKey();
            if (Walkable == true)
            {
                if (mov.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    PX--;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(PX + 1, PY);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                if (mov.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    PX++;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(PX - 1, PY);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                if (mov.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    PY--;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(PX, PY + 1);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                if (mov.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    PY++;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(PX, PY - 1);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static void Draw()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        for (int x = 35; x <= 75; x++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 5);
            Console.Write(Wall, Walkable = false);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, 20);
            Console.Write(Wall, Walkable = false);
        }
        for (int y = 5; y <= 20; y++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(35, y);
            Console.Write(Wall, Walkable = false);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(75, y);
            Console.Write(Wall, Walkable = false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

it writes out both the player and the Room where the game shall take place, but i can not for my life find a way to get "Null" or the empty background to be walkable at the same time as the walls are not, same as i don't know how to maybe fill the inside of the box with dots "." or something.

any help or feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: **Pro Tip** Adding that your new to programming and C# is totally irrelevant, also "*it won't work*" is not a technical description of a problem. How doesn't it work? what does it do? what do you expect it do? What part do you think is the problem? have you debugged your code? Since you have where does it seem to be going wrong?

Comment: What do you think `Console.Write(Wall, Walkable = false);` does? It seems `Walkable` shouldn’t be a fixed scalar (like it currently is), but rather depend on `(PX, PY)` – so either be a computed value or a two-dimensional matrix of booleans reflecting where your walls aren’t.